# Should I wait for the actual value to display anything or display a default value?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, user-experience

I am updating a boolean in a Preferences [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore).

```
// helper function for optimistic updates (takes 10ms instead of ~40ms)
@Composable
fun <V> Preference<V>.optimisticState(): MutableState<V> {
    val optimisticState = remember { mutableStateOf<V>(defaultValue) }

    // initialize with saved value
    val dataStore = LocalDataStore.current
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = null, block = {
        val savedState = flow(dataStore).first()
        if (savedState != null) {
            optimisticState.value = savedState
        }
    })

    // override setter
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    return object : MutableState<V> by optimisticState {
        override var value: V
            get() = optimisticState.value
            set(value) {
                // change state immediately and then save the new value
                optimisticState.value = value
                scope.launch {
                    edit(dataStore) { value }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the default value is different from the saved value, the `Switch` is briefly animated. (Is there a way to temporarily turn off the animations?)

[image: switch preference]

```
@Composable
fun SwitchPreference(title: String, preference: BooleanPreference) {
    var checked by preference.optimisticState()

    PreferenceItem(title = title, action = {
        Switch(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = { checked = it })
    }, onClick = { checked = !checked })
}
```

I could conditionally render the `Switch`, but then nothing would be displayed for a brief moment while the saved value is being fetched. (I added a `delay`)
[image: wait for actual value]